# spring security tags for html

Tags: html, spring, spring-security, roles

I am trying to hide different html content based on what role is logged in.
I set the namespace:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">
```

And then I tried something like this:

```
     <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
          <li><a href="/users">User Management</a></li>
     </security:authorize>
```

However I am getting this error message:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-6] Fatal error during parsing
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of 
well-formed character data or markup.
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><label id="label-mhealth">mHealth Store</label></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            < class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Product Management <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/products">Product List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                <li><a href="/users">User Management</a></li>
            </security:authorize>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the complete template. No. but I just added it to my pom.xml and it still is not working

Comment: Add < %@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="security" %> taglib declaration at the top of the jsp instead of using it on html element.

Comment: also, '< class="nav navbar-nav">' is not correct. Should be '<div class="nav navbar-nav">' I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Spring Security JSP tag with Thymeleaf.
Replace the following one

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
       <li><a href="/users">User Management</a></li>
</security:authorize>
```

with this one

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <li><a href="/users">User Management</a></li>
</div>
```

Add thymeleaf th:sec namespace if you haven't yet.
Check here [Thymeleaf Spring Security Integration](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html) (Look for Spring Security Dialect)